# Contractions of à + les

Tags: grammaire

We know that contractions are mandatory in French language, for example:

> Je vais (à + les) aux États-Unis, etc.

Can we contract the à + les in this sentence?

> "J'apprends à les comprendre" -> "J'apprends aux comprendre"

Comment: This *les* is a pronom meaning *them*,  not the definite article.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the same case. In the former sentence les is the plural article: *les États-Unis*. Contraction takes place as you said: *Je vais (à + les) aux États-Unis*. In the latter sentence, *les* is pronoun (pronom in French) that replaces an [accusative case (complément d'objet direct)](http://weblatinus.free.fr/manuel/5/chaos/dii/accusatif__complment_dobjet_direct.html#:%7E:text=L%27accusatif%20d%C3%A9signe%20le%20compl%C3%A9ment,fait%20para%C3%AEtre%20%C2%BB%20directement%20sans%20pr%C3%A9position.&text=Le%20compl%C3%A9ment%20d%27objet%20direct,action%20exprim%C3%A9e%20par%20le%20verbe.).

> J'apprends à comprendre les règles du rugby.

> J'apprends à les comprendre.

Note that comprendre is a so-called *[verbe transitif direct](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-3610.php#:%7E:text=Le%20compl%C3%A9ment%20d%27objet%20est%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralement%20plac%C3%A9%20apr%C3%A8s%20le%20verbe,%27interm%C3%A9diaire%20d%27une%20pr%C3%A9position.)*.

To try to simplify even more: in "Je vais aux toilettes", "aux" translates into "to the..." ; in "j'arrive à les comprendre", "les" translates into "them"; "à" (or "de") is simply required by the verb "arriver" when followed with a complement.  (merci @wazoox:-)!)

Comment: Parfois, ce *les* non fusionné avec *à* reste quand même un article ou du moins, c'est ce que [certains "superprofs"](https://www.superprof.fr/diplome-baccalaureat-scientifique-saurais-aider-eleves-scientifiques-point-positif.html) semblent croire... : *Pour moi le cours en classe et le cours avec moi ce n'est pas la même chose, le professeur est la pour vous donner les informations, et moi je suis la pour vous aider à les **comprendres** et à **les exercées**.*  ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. Je ne comprends bien. Dois-je corriger/modifier quelque chose ?

Comment: @jlliagre En effet : "je suis la pour vous aider à les comprendres et à les exercées" Une phrase pleine de fautes, non ?

Comment: Oui, pleine de fautes, non, rien à corriger dans ta réponse :-) C'était juste pour te montrer qu'il ne fallait pas t'étonner du niveau de français de certains étudiants. L'auteur de ces lignes dit avoir un bac scientifique.

Comment: To try to simplify even more: in "Je vais aux toilettes", "aux" translates into "to the..." ; in "j'arrive à les comprendre", "les" translates into "them"; "à" (or "de") is simply required by the verb "arriver" when followed with a complement. A literal translation would be: "I'm coming to understanding them". "à" is "to", and "les" is "them".

Comment: Merci beaucoup, ça m'a aidé vraiment!